# swiftUI - Multiple map views and app design question

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I have an application setup in the following configuration and I dont think its correct. Looking for suggestions on how to implement this without having 2 separate map views instantiate.

My second question is, IF this is the correct. When I switch between tabs the view span changes slightly, How do I correct that?

Lastly, is there a better wait to implement side by side views than using NavigationView {}?

1. **TabView** -> holds two views:

```
  var body: some View {
          
      TabView {
          ListView()
              .tabItem{
                  Label("List", systemImage: "list.bullet.clipboard")
                      }
          MapView()
              .tabItem {
                  Label("map", systemImage: "map")
                  }
          }
      
  }
}
```

2. A **listView** with navigationView {that has the listView.swift and the mapView.swift}. I did this so I can get the list and map side by side

```
    NavigationView {
            ListView()
            MapView()
        }
```

3. The **MapView** (same one referenced in the listView)

```
    struct MapView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var mapViewModel = MapViewModel()    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Map(coordinateRegion: $mapViewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
            .onAppear {
                mapViewModel.checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: *'side by side'* - are you looking for `HStack`?

Comment: No not really - I need a dynamic list over a map view that changes with orientation, etc

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. What is wrong with this implementation?